# How can I join these two org-templates, so that the first block can be an option between the other entries?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

```
(use-package org
  :ensure org-plus-contrib)

    (use-package org-contacts
      :ensure nil
      :after org)

(use-package org-capture
  :ensure nil
  :after org
  :preface
  (defvar my/org-contacts-template "* %(org-contacts-template-name)
:PROPERTIES:
:ALIAS: %^{hefis}
:NICKNAME: %^{hefistion}
:PHONE: %^{123-456-789}
:PHONE: %^{123-456-789}
:EMAIL: %(org-contacts-template-email)
:EMAIL: %(org-contacts-template-email)
:ADDRESS: %^{289 Cleveland St. Brooklyn, 11206 NY, USA}
:BIRTHDAY: %^{dd-mm-yyyy}
:NOTE: %^{NOTE}
:END:" "Template for org-contacts.")
  :custom
  (org-capture-templates
   `(("c" "Contact" entry (file+headline "~/org~/Gtd_mylife/org-capture_tpls/my-contacts.org" "Friends"),
  my/org-contacts-template
  :empty-lines 1))))
```

---

```
    (define-key global-map "\C-cc" 'org-capture)

 (setq org-capture-templates
       '(("a" "Appointment" entry
      (file+headline
       (concat org-directory "~/Gtd_mylife/org-capture_tpls/my-appointments.org")
       "Calendar")
      "* APPT %^{Description} %^g\n%?\nAdded: %U")

     ("m" "Brain" entry (function org-brain-goto-end)
        "* %i%?" :empty-lines 1)

  ;;  for todo tasks

 ("d" "Long Tail TODO Task" entry
  (file+headline "" "Tasks")
  "* TODO %?\n  %u\n  %a")

  ;; for tasks

 ("t" "Task Diary" entry
  (file+datetree
   (concat org-directory "~/Gtd_mylife/org-capture_tpls/taskdiary.org"))
  "* TODO %^{Description}  %^g\n%?\nAdded: %U")

  ;;  for long tail tasks

 ("d" "Long Tail TODO Task" entry
  (file+headline "" "Tasks")
  "* TODO %?\n  %u\n  %a")

;; for general notes

 ("n" "Notes" entry
  (file+datetree
   (concat org-directory "~/Gtd_mylife/org-capture_tpls/my-notes.org"))

      "* %^{Description} %^g %?\nAdded: %U")

;; for dreams 

 ("i" "Dreams" entry
  (file+datetree
   (concat org-directory "~/Gtd_mylife/org-capture_tpls/my-dreams.org"))

  "* %^{Description} %^g %?\nAdded: %U")

;; for journalling 

     ("j" "Journal" entry
      (file+datetree
       (concat org-directory "~/Gtd_mylife/org-capture_tpls/my-journal.org"))
      "** %^{Heading}")

;; for hugo blogging

       ("o" "Posts"
     (file+datetree (concat org-directory "~/blog/content/posts/my-post.org")
"* TODO %^{Description}  %^g\n%?\nAdded: %U"))

 ;; for capturing books to read

       ("b" "Book" entry (file+headline "~/Gtd_mylife/org-capture_tpls/books-to_read.org" "books to read")
      "* TODO %\\1 - %\\2%?\n%U\n:PROPERTIES:\n:NAME: %^{NAME}\n:TITLE: %^{TITLE}\n:END:\n")

 ;; for log time 

       ("l" "Log Time" entry
      (file+datetree
       (concat org-directory "~/Gtd_mylife/org-capture_tpls/timelog.org"))
      "** %U - %^{Activity}  :TIME:")

 ;; for capturing chunks of webpages and/or webpages themselves with W3m or EWW 

       ("w" "Website" plain 
      (function org-website-clipper)
      "* %a\n%T\n" :immediate-finish t)))
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 --> https://github.com/rememberYou/.emacs.d/issues/4